# How do I delete specific words in arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, fgets

I want to delete all words that have greater than 5 letters from a .txt file. 
In my first step I have read all words in a array of char pointers with fgets. 
Now I have no idea how I can continue. 
I would be grateful if someone could help me. What I got so far:

```
    int main () {
        FILE *fp;
        char str[2500];

        fp= fopen("a.txt" , "r");
        if (fp==NULL) { 
            perror("Error opening file");
            return(-1); 
        }

        fgets (str, 2500, fp)!=NULL

        fclose(fp);
        return(0);
   }
```

Comment: where is your code? what have you tried? what is the error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a free homework service

Comment: That is only one small part of my homework. Would it be helpful if I post my code that only includes a fgets ? I have searched about this topic but found no information to my question.

Comment: You have to include a [mcve]. This kind of thing is worrisome: "I have read all words in a array of char pointers with fgets." Each of the pointers in that array must point to some allocated memory; you aren't really reading words into an array of pointers.

Comment: look at `strlen` probably want to write `if (strlen(arr[i]) < 6)` somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Think about how to do this.  You need to delete all words greater than five (5) letters.  Another way to think about this is you want to copy all words that are five (5) letters or less.

Get a word.  Measure it.  If you need to keep it, write it out (to a new file).

Repeat.

At the end, you have two files: the input (with all words) and the output (all five (5) or less letters).

Now what do you do?